# Silverlight 5 fails the first time to consume a Web API 2 [clientaccesspolicy.xml]

Tags: c#, silverlight, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, webclient

Bit or no information with regard to network my problem.

I try to consume a Web API hosted on different server (localhost:/9000) by libraries: HttpClient in Silverlight 5 project (localhost:/8080).

The detail is that with WebClient works perfectly, because before you get the "**clientaccesspolicy.xml**" file, called service does (so I interpret):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
client.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:9000/api/Orders"));
return ordersList;
```

Not so with HttpClient in the first attempt fails: "*TaskCanceledException*" by TimeOut, once (by Fiddler) completes the action, then get perfectly: **cap.xml**, **and on the second attempt** of method invocation works if the Web API in JSON format.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://localhost:9000/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                try
                {
                    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15000);
                    var response = await client.GetStringAsync("api/Orders").ConfigureAwait(false);
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ClassOrders>>(response);
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException h)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(h.Message);
                }
                catch (TimeoutException t)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(t.Message);
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException c)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(c.Message);
                }
            }

ConfigureAwait(false); //I may return if the asynchronous method fails (not frozen in subthread)
```

Comment: In the HTTPClient sample the URI is pointing to 8080 and not 9000

Comment: @Kar, the API is hosted on "9000" (port example) and WebApp -cliente- in "8080". Example: http://webapi.com and customer SL5 http://MyApp.com

Both are separate hosting. And if you were right in the code, and it was corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, with the help of [this article](http://www.kastory.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=25:rest-web-service-in-c-with-silverlight-and-asp-net-web-api&catid=32&Itemid=130) I could get the answer.

ConfigureAwait(false) prevented navigate on the result, and of course the task was canceled due to long wait under the wire.

... ().Wait() and ConfigureAwait() will have other more worthy uses, my mistake was thinking that without them it was not possible to capture errors request, which HttpRequestException was there to rescue me.